# UITextField with "multiple" delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm trying to create a text field that would be able to respond to the following:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

To do so i have a UITextField subclass which is a delegate for itself:

```
[self setDelegate:self]
```

- Problem no. 1: on ios5 device the app crashes as soon as you tap on the text field that has a delegate set to self
- Problem no. 2: i still need some text fields to be able to send delegate notifications to other objects.

QUESTION: What would be the easiest way to implement delegate methods in a subclass, but still allowing an outside object to be a delegate as well and recieve the same messages?

Thanks

Comment: First of all what is the scenario, why do you what to subclass `UITextField`?

Comment: For problem #1. This is a known issue with Xcode 11.2. Make sure you are on the latest Xcode version to fix.

Answer (score 15):

I was having the exact same issue (in **Swift 3**). I solved the problem *overriding* the `delegate` property from the `UITextField` class.

During my custom view initialization, I *hook up* my own internal delegate:

```swift
class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initCustomTextField()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initCustomTextField()
    }

    private func initCustomTextField() {
        super.delegate = self // Note the super qualifier.
    }

    ...
```

Now we need to *override* the aforementioned `delegate` property:

```
private weak var userDelegate: UITextFieldDelegate?

override var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? {
    get { return userDelegate }
    set { userDelegate = newValue }
}
```

Finally, on each `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol method you must *forward* the call to the external delegate, if any:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Do your thing here, and then forward:
    return self.delegate?.textFieldShouldBeginEditing?(self) ?? true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // Do your thing here, and then forward:
    self.delegate?.textFieldDidBeginEditing?(self)
}

...
```

One caveat if you plan to support **iOS 10** as well:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.delegate?.textFieldDidEndEditing?(self)
}

/// This method will be called, instead of the above, on iOS ≥ 10.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
    self.delegate?.textFieldDidEndEditing?(self, reason: reason)
}
```

Comment: Best answer. Thanks ;)

Comment: This pattern doesn't work with `UITextView` and `UITextViewDelegate` unfortunately. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Notifications`.
Make it that text field post notification, like the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"custom notification name" object:self];
```

and add observer to the class which is supposed to be external delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cacheUpdated:) name:@"custom notification name" object:nil];
```

That way, text field post notification which means it took a certain action and your external delegate class will be notified since it's already been listening to that kind of notifications. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For creating you own delegate you need to define new protocol into your subclass

```
@protocol MyUItestFieldDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)customUITextFieldDelegateMethod;

@end
```

which you can use into your controller like

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyUItestFieldDelegate>
```